# How to automatically unpack a set of files compressed in bz2 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have many files (.bz2) inside the same directory in a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I can manually unpack each one of the files by using bzip2 -dk filename.bz2 but I assume there is a way to do this automatically since they are many files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all files are in single directory,

You can do `bzip2 -d -k *.bz2` where `-d` means decompress as bzip2 by default is for compression and `-k` means keep the input files and `*.bz2` tells `bzip2` to search for every single file ending with `.bz2` extension to be extracted.
Also you can use `bunzip2 -k *.bz2` as `bunzip2` by default is for decompression so no need for `-d` command.

if you prefer bash scripting, You can also use a `for`loop

```
for b in *.bz2; do bunzip2 $b; done
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. While answers are always welcome, please consider adding some context explaining *how* the above answers the original question :)